# How do I determine what items to add to my "restricted-shell-escape" safe list?

Tags: packages, shell-escape

I am trying to follow [the MacTeX-2012 instructions](http://tug.org/mactex/TeXLive2012Changes.pdf) for migrating from (unsafe) `shell-escape` to using "restricted-shell-escape". But it is unclear to me what items to put in the file that specifies the "safe list" for this mode.

For example, if I remove `shell-escape` from my command line (or, disable it from the warning dialog in TeXShop), and try to use a package that requires it, like, for example, `auto-pst-pdf` I get an error:

**"You need to run LaTeX with the equivalent of "pdflatex -shell-escape" Or turn off auto-pst-pdf."**

when processing even the simplest of files:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}
Test. 
\end{document}
```

I also notice that I get other warnings, even with this simple example, such as

**"Package ifplatform Warning: Shell escape is disabled, so I can only detect \ifwindows"**

and wonder if there is a way to avoid these, and the corresponding loss of functionality using "restricted-shell-escape" -- or at least find out what I'm missing without scanning the log.

What items do I need to add to my `texmf.cnf` to get `auto-pst-pdf` to work without enabling `shell-escape`? How, in general, do I determine what items should be in this list? Are there some things that will *only* work with the `shell-scape` flag, and not with "restricted-shell-escape"; how can I determine what those are?

---

The (local) `texmf.cnf` file:

```
shell_escape_commands = bibtex,bibtex8,kpsewhich,makeindex,mpost,repstopdf
```

Comment: The `pdftex` binary provided with the pretest version had a bug, which seems to have been corrected in the release version. Try the sample file you find in [this message](http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2012-June/031821.html) by Reinhard Kotucha which used to trigger the bug, but in my TeX Live 2012/Mac TeX works correctly. However this *doesn't* work (and *never* has) with XeTeX.

Comment: It's actually the [`hardwrap`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hardwrap) package that uses the shell-escape. (The `hardwrap` package is used by later versions of `tufte-latex` to word-wrap the log messages nicely.)

Comment: @godbyk: If the cause is `hardwrap`, what can I do to avoid the error?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: Can you post your complete .log file? It could be that we need to rework the logic in `hardwrap` or that there's an issue with your installation.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius I don't know why you have the buggy version of `pdftex`; but the production date your `pdflatex` format is *before*  the release date of TeX Live, so it seems that you have the pretest version of the binary. Run TeX Live Utility and update all.

Comment: Remark, looks like mpost is unsafe, [Security in autogenerated latex scripts. How to avoid LaTeX Injection? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/552887/security-in-autogenerated-latex-scripts-how-to-avoid-latex-injection)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would avoid modifying the list of programs allowed to run in the restricted shell. These are either programs that don't write out any output (and when output redirection is requested they don't work in the restricted shell escape setting) or respect the `openout_any` setting in `texmf.cnf`.

As far as the present problem is concerned, running `pdflatex` with shell escape enabled on the file `filename.tex` consists in using the command line

```
pdflatex -shell-escape filename
```

(no quotes).

How to setup a front-end to run this command depends on the front-end itself. With TeXShop, for example, one can define a new engine. In your `~/Library/TeXShop/Engines` folder duplicate `XeLaTeX.engine` and call it `pdflatexshell.engine`. Modify the file (with TeXShop itself) to read

```
#!/bin/tcsh

set path= (/usr/texbin /usr/local/bin $path)
pdflatex -shell-escape "$1"
```

and, for a file you want to compile with unrestricted shell escape, write at its beginning

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatexshell
```

so that the engine will be automatically selected on opening.

What to do with other front-ends or LyX will vary.

---

If you really want to use the restricted shell escape, you have to enable

```
uname
rm
echo
latex
```

The program list can be determined by searching for `runsystem` in the `.log` file.

Comment: So basically, one should just run shell-excape when needed, rather than enable specific programs? That seems like a not-so-optimal solution, since instead of picking a *few* programs to always allow, one ends up occasionally (perhaps frequently) allowing *all* programs.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius If the document comes from an untrusted source, run it without shell escape and look for `system` in the log file to see what it attempted to do during compilation.

Comment: I'd still be curious: what program would I need to add to the list (on OS X) to get `auto-pst-pdf` to work without `shell-escape`? Adding `gs` doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: Note that (I think?) allowing `latex` is effectively equivalent to allowing the whole shell escape, because the evil program can just invoke `latex --shell-escape <evil TeX code>`.

Comment: In this case `auto-pst-pdf` explicitly check for `ifshellescape` (see the source code) so I guess it's necessary to load `ifplatform` before then invoke `\shellescapetrue` or something similar?

Comment: @user202729 Reply to the first comment: yes. To the second: maybe, I didn’t check.